# Probability of ties under for IID random variables with continuous CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_1,X_2$ are IID with continuous CDF $F$. I would like to show that
$$
\Pr(X_1>X_2)=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
By symmetry, we have $\Pr(X_1>X_2)=\Pr(X_2>X_1)$ but how do I show rigorously that $\Pr(X_1=X_2)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chandu1729 has dealt with the *absolutely continuous* case, and the continuous case is not much different. Let $\mu$ be the probability measure on $\Bbb R$ with cdf $F$. The continuity of $F$ means that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$.
The joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is the product measure $\mu\otimes\mu$; in particular,
$$
P(X_1=X_2)=P((X_1,X_2)\in D)=\mu\otimes\mu(D),
$$
where $D:=\{(x,x)\in\Bbb R^2:x\in\Bbb R\}$. Now use Fubini to write $\mu\otimes\mu(D)$ as an iterated integral, and evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

As $F$ is continuous, $X_1$ and $X_2$ will have density function $f$. If $A$ is Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have the following :

$$P((X_1,X_2) \in A) = \int_A f(x) f(y) dxdy$$

Hence, $P(X_1=X_2) = \int_{y=x}f(x)f(y)dxdy$

Since, the set $A=\{(x,y):y=x\}$ is of Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $P(X_1=X_2)=0$.